# Expanding a l3 variable to split it

Tags: expansion, latex3

I need to expand the variable `\pmbc_bounds_tl` to split it. I've tried playing around with `exp_args` without success. Which version of `exp_args` should I use?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \pmbc_bounds_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
%  \seq_show:N  \l_tmpa_seq
    
  \seq_pop_left:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \pmbc_bounds_tl { } {
    BOUNDS ~ PB !
  }
%  \tl_show:N \pmbc_bounds_tl
  
% WHICH VERSION TO USE?
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { : } { \pmbc_bounds_tl }
  \seq_show:N  \l_tmpb_seq
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

TEST.

\begin{foo}
    a = b : c ;
    d = e : f
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seq_set_split:NnV`

Comment: Careful with using `:` in ExplSyntax because the category code is different.

Comment: So the solution is then `\seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpb_seq { \c_colon_str } { \pmbc_bounds_tl }`.

Comment: @User23456234 "Oups" for the colons....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to access the `V`alue of the tl variable, but you also have to take care that the colon is different in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` than in normal setting.

If you want to split at the colon something stored in `\l_pmbc_bounds_tl`, then the correct method is

```
\seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpb_seq \c_colon_str \l_pmbc_bounds_tl
```

Note that braces should *always* be omitted when the argument type is `N` or `V` and that *every* variable should announce its scope (`l` or `g` or `c`) in its name: `\pmbc_bounds_tl` is an invalid name.

Every function that has `n` in its signature can have a variant with `V` replacing `n`, in this case we use `\seq_set_split:Nnn` but in the variant `\seq_set_split:NVV`.

This variant is predefined, but it's not always the case. If it turns out that LaTeX balks about a variant not being defined, it's better to use the standard method of performing

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn
```

rather than trying with some `\exp_args:...` function: the code will gain in clarity and the performance is not hindered in a significant way.

Thinking in terms of macro expansion isn't the right approach in this situation, because it's rather “accessing the value” and the fact that this is internally implemented with macro expansion should not be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first two comments, the solution is given above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_pmbc_bounds_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
%  \seq_show:N  \l_tmpa_seq
    
  \seq_pop_left:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \l_pmbc_bounds_tl { } {
    BOUNDS ~ PB !
  }
%  \tl_show:N \l_pmbc_bounds_tl

  \seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpb_seq \c_colon_str \l_pmbc_bounds_tl
  \seq_show:N  \l_tmpb_seq
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

TEST.

\begin{foo}
    a = b : c ;
    d = e : f
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that semantically there should be no braces around `\pmbc_bounds_tl` if it's a `V` argument: `\seq_set_split:NVV \l_tmpb_seq \c_colon_str \pmbc_bounds_tl` is correct. Also, please note that `\pmbc_bounds_tl` is not a valid variable name, it misses the scope. It should be `\l_pmbc_bounds_tl`.

Comment: I've updated my code using your advice. Thanks!